# How can I find out the Elastic Beanstalk environment a given EC2 instance is running on from the CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application deployed to Elastic Beanstalk with the Mutli-Container Docker configuration, which is backed by ECS and further backed by EC2. When I SSH onto the EC2 instance, is there some command I can run to identify the name of the EB application / environment that it's running under? Is there anything like `aws elasticbeanstalk get-current-environment`?

Comment: I don't think there is, but you can use an environment variable to identify the environment on the EC2 instance.

Comment: The EB environment name and id is present in your instance tags. You could try `aws ec2 describe-tags` command to get the environment name. Please note: you would need an IAM role attached to the instances with `ec2:DescribeTags` permission for this command to work.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR your comment here is the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, I will type that up as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EB environment name and id is present in your instance tags. You could run the AWS CLI: `aws ec2 describe-tags` to get the environment name. The tag keys would be:

- elasticbeanstalk:environment-id
- elasticbeanstalk:environment-name

Please note: you would need an IAM role attached to the instances with `ec2:DescribeTags` permission for this command to work.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a beginner in AWS as well but I believe you are able to enter:

***eb status***

This will show:

***Environment details for: xxxx***

Application name: xxxx

Region: us-east-1

Deployed Version: app-xxxxx

Environment ID: xxxxx

Platform: xxxx/Python 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.6.5

Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0

CNAME: xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com

Updated: 2018-04-13 19:10:45.354000+00:00

Status: Ready

Health: Green

Comment: The awsebcli does not come preconfigured on EC2 instances that are launched by EB. That tool is more meant to be used outside of the individual servers that back EB